# C beginner, code not outputting properly

Tags: c, printf, output, scanf

So I am very new to coding and this is the first time I have used scanf and printf to this extent. For my homework assignment we are supposed to create a program that calculates fuel efficiency in mpg and liters per 100km. The final answer is only supposed to have 2 decimal points... but that is another story. ;P

Right now, the program lets me enter a value for the first part (how many miles), however, once I click enter it skips to the end of my code and spews out a (seemingly) random number?

```
#include <stdio.h> /* tells computer where to find definitions for printf and scanf */
#define KMS_PER_MILE 1.61 /* conversion constant for miles to kms */
#define LIT_PER_GAL 3.79 /* conversion constant for gallons to liters */

int main(void)
{
    double miles, /* input - distance in miles. */
    gallons, /* input - gallons consumed */
    mpg, /* output - miles per gallon */
    kms, /* output - kilometers */
    liters, /* output - liters */
    lpkm; /* output - liters per 100 kms */

    /* get the distance in miles */
    printf("Enter the distance in miles> ");
    scanf("%1f", &miles);

    /* get the gallons consumed */
    printf("Enter the gallons consumed> ");
    scanf("%1f", &gallons);

    /* convert to mpg */
    mpg = (double)miles / (double)gallons;

    /* convert to lpkm */
    liters = LIT_PER_GAL * gallons;
    kms = KMS_PER_MILE * miles;
    lpkm = (double)liters / (double)kms * 100;

    /* Display fuel efficiency in mpg and lpkm */
    printf("The car's fuel efficiency is\n %1f mpg \n %1f liters per 100 kms", mpg, lpkm);
    return (0);

}
```

Comment: Your title says that you are a C++ beginner and your code is pure C.

Comment: `return` is not a function, get rid of the parentheses. And in C++, respectively since C99, you can leave `return 0;` off in `main`, it's implicit (but only there). Also, while this code is valid C and valid C++, that's probably just luck considering you are a beginner. I suggest only tagging the language you are writing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Printing you can use *1f* but during taking input you must use **lf** .

Answer (score 8):

Try to change `%1f` to `%lf` in `scanf`.

For more details look [C++ reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/)

Comment: @celeste avoid using a font where `1` and `l` look too similar when programming.

Answer (score 2):

Since you claim to be learning C++, if you had used the C++ standard library you would have avoided the problem:

```
#include <iostream> // std::cin, std::cout

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Enter the distance in miles> ";
  std::cin >> miles;
  std::cout << "Enter the gallons consumed> "
  std::cin >> gallons;
  ....

  std::cout << "The car's fuel efficiency is\n" << mpg << "\n" 
            <<  lpkm << " per 100 kms\n";
}
```